# Java Vending machine assignment how to do removeItemType and reStock?

Tags: java

I have a vending machine project where I have to complete the methods. A few aren't done yet you can ignore those for this question. The part I'm stuck on and want help with is the is the removeItemType and the reStock.

This is my code

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class VendingMachine {
      private int changeAmount;
      private int bankAmount;
      private int depositedAmount;
      private ItemType [] items;
      private int index;
      private int itemCount;
      private int itemPrice;
  // Initializes the float and certain values for the vending machine
  public VendingMachine() 
  {
      changeAmount = 1000;
      items = new ItemType[10];
      index = 0;
      itemCount = 0;
      itemPrice = 0;
  }
  
  public int getBankAmount()
  {
      return bankAmount + changeAmount;
  }
  public int getDepositAmount()
  {
      return this.depositedAmount;
  }
   public int getChangeAmount()
  {
      return this.changeAmount;
  }
  

  public boolean addItemType(ItemType item) 
  {
    if (itemCount > 10 && itemPrice % 5 == 0)     
    {       
      return false;
    }
    else{
     items[itemCount] = item;
     itemCount++;
     return true;
    }
  }

  public boolean removeItemType(int index) 
  {
    if (index < 0)
    {
      return false;
  }
    else
    itemCount = index;
    index--;
   return true;
  }
 
  public boolean reStock(int which, int qty) 
{
    if (index < 0)
    {
      return false;
  }
    else
      
   return true;
  }
 
  public boolean depositCoin(int coin) 
  {
      return false;
  }
 
  public int selectItem(int index) 
  {
     changeAmount = this.depositedAmount - this.bankAmount;
      return 0;
  }
  public int clearMoney() 
  {
   
      return 0;
  }  
  
  // Returns a formatted string of the list of items in the vending machine
  public String toString() 
  {
      String output = "\n" + StringFormatter("IndexID", 10) + 
      StringFormatter("Name", 15) +  StringFormatter("Price", 10) + 
      StringFormatter("Quantity",10);    
      output += "\n***********************************************\n";
      // add the items of the vending machine to the output string
    
      if (itemCount == 0){
            output +=("Machine not stocked");
      }
       for(int i=0; i<itemCount; i++){
                output +=("\n"+NumberFormatter(i, 2) + StringFormatter("", 8)+
                                  StringFormatter(items[i].getName(),13) + 
                                  NumberFormatter(items[i].getPrice(), 7) + 
                                  StringFormatter("", 6)+
                                  NumberFormatter(items[i].getQuantity(), 5));  
            }
            output += ("\n");
   
    return output;
  }
  /***********************************************************************
    * Do not modify the code below. They are functions to assist you with 
    * this assignment
    ***********************************************************************/
  
  /* this method takes in an integer value and field width. It return
   * a string of length fWidth with the integer value right justified    
   */
  static public String NumberFormatter(int value, int fWidth) {
    DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("########");
    String output = myFormatter.format(value); 
    String filler = "";
    if (fWidth - output.length() < 0 ){
      return output.substring(0, fWidth);
    }
    else{
      for(int i=0; i < fWidth - output.length(); i++)
      {
        filler = filler + " ";
      }   
      return filler+output;
    }
  }
  /* this method takes in an double value and field width. It return
   * a string of length fWidth with the double value right justified 
   * with two digits to the right of the the decimal point
   */
  static public String NumberFormatter(double value, int fWidth) {
    DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("########.00");
    String output = myFormatter.format(value); 
    String filler = "";
    if (fWidth - output.length() < 0 ){
      return output.substring(0, fWidth);
    }
    else{
      for(int i=0; i < fWidth - output.length(); i++)
      {
        filler = filler + " ";
      }   
      return filler+output;
    }
  }
  /* this method takes in an string value and field width. It return
   * a string of length fwidth with the string value left justified 
   */
  static public String StringFormatter(String value, int fWidth) {
    String output = value.trim();
    String filler = "";
    if (fWidth - output.length() < 0 ){
      return output.substring(0, fWidth);
    }
    else{
      for(int i=0; i < fWidth - output.length(); i++)
      {
        filler = filler + " ";
      }   
      return output+filler;
    }
  }  
  
}
```

This is the part I need help with... The removeItemType should only be removing the item that I select but right now will remove all the items that were added from the one I select and below. And Im totally lost on the Restock I tried a few things but since they didn't compile I got rid of it before posting here. Its supposed do this...

public boolean reStock(int which, int qty)
Restock the specified item type, adding the quantity specified.
Parameters:
which - the index of the item type to be restocked.
qty - the quantity of the item to add to the specified item type.
Returns:
False - if the specified index is out of bounds.
Returns true otherwise

```
public boolean removeItemType(int index) 
  {
    if (index < 0)
    {
      return false;
  }
    else
    itemCount = index;
    index--;
   return true;
  }
 
  public boolean reStock(int which, int qty) 
{
    if (index < 0)
    {
      return false;
  }
    else
      
   return true;
  }
```

This is my Itemtype

```
public class ItemType 
{
  private String name;
  private double price;
  private int quantity;
  public ItemType(String n, int p)
  {
    this.quantity = 0;
    this.name = n;
    if (p <= 0){
      this.price = 5;
    }
    else{
      this.price = p;
    }
  }
  public String getName()
  {
    return this.name;      
  }
  public int getPrice()
  {
    return (int) this.price;      
  }
  public int getQuantity()
  {
    return this.quantity;
  }  
  public int addQuantity(int n) 
  {
    if (quantity <0) {
    return -9999;  
    }
    else{
      if (quantity + n <= 10) 
        quantity += n;
      return quantity;
  }
  }
  public int getItem() 
  {
    if (quantity < 1){
      return -9999;
    }
    else
      this.quantity --;
    return quantity;
    
  }
  
}
```

This is my driver

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

class VendingDriver2 extends JFrame implements KeyListener, ActionListener{
    
    // vending machine variables
    ArrayList<ItemType> myOnHandList;
    VendingMachine myVendingMachine;
    
    
    // Name-constants for the various dimensions
    public static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 400;
    public static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 400;
    public static final Color MENU_BACKGROUND = Color.BLUE;
    public static final Color VENDING_BACKGROUND = Color.GREEN;
    public static final Color ONHAND_BACKGROUND = Color.RED;
    
    // the custom drawing canvas (extends JPanel)
    private JPanel canvasOnHand;
    private JPanel canvasVending; 
    private JPanel canvasMenu;
    
    private JTextArea menuText;
    private JTextField optionTextF;
    
    private JTextArea vendingText;
    private JTextArea onHandText;
    
    private String option;
    
    /** Constructor to set up the GUI */
    public VendingDriver2(){
        
        myOnHandList = new ArrayList<ItemType>();
        myVendingMachine = new VendingMachine();
       
        canvasMenu = new JPanel();
        canvasMenu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT));
        canvasMenu.setLayout(new BoxLayout(canvasMenu, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        
        menuText = new JTextArea(24,50);
        menuText.setLineWrap(true);
        menuText.setEditable(false);
        menuText.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        menuText.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 12));
        
        optionTextF = new JTextField(5);
        optionTextF.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 16));
        optionTextF.addActionListener(this);
        
        canvasMenu.add(menuText);
        canvasMenu.add(optionTextF);
        
        canvasMenu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT));
        
        canvasOnHand = new JPanel();
        canvasOnHand.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT));
        onHandText = new JTextArea(24,50);
        onHandText.setLineWrap(true);
        onHandText.setEditable(false);
        onHandText.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        onHandText.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 12));
        canvasOnHand.add(onHandText);
                
        canvasVending = new JPanel();
        canvasVending.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT));
        vendingText = new JTextArea(24,50);
        vendingText.setLineWrap(true);
        vendingText.setEditable(false);
        vendingText.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        vendingText.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 12));
        canvasVending.add(vendingText);
        
        // Add panel to this JFrame
        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        
        cp.add(canvasMenu);
        cp.add(canvasVending);
        cp.add(canvasOnHand);
        
         canvasMenu.setBackground(MENU_BACKGROUND);
         canvasVending.setBackground(VENDING_BACKGROUND);
         canvasOnHand.setBackground(ONHAND_BACKGROUND);
        
        
        // "this" JFrame fires KeyEvent
        addKeyListener(this);
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        // Handle the CLOSE button
        setTitle("Vending Machine");
        // pack all the components in the JFrame
        pack();           
        // show it
        setVisible(true); 
        requestFocus();          
    }
    
    public void displayMenu(){
        
        menuText.setText("MENU OPTIONS \n\nWhat would you like to do?"+
                         "\n\n********** ITEM TYPE **********"+
                         "\n[1]  Create a new item type"+
                         "\n[2]  Add quantity to an item"+
                         "\n\n********** VENDING MACHINE **********"+
                         "\n[3]  Add an item type to the machine"+           
                         "\n[4]  Remove an item type on the machine"+
                         "\n[5]  Restock an item type on the machine"+
                         "\n[6]  Deposit Coin"+
                         "\n[7]  Select Item to Purchase"+
                         "\n\n********** MISCELLANEOUS **********"+
                         "\n[8]  Reset/clear the items types"+
                         "\n[9]  Reset/clear the vending machine"+
                         "\n[10] Clear the money from machine"+
                         "\n[11] End program");       
        updateScreen();
       
    }
    public void processOptionSelected(){
        
        if(option.trim().equals("")){
            displayMenu();
        }
        
        else if (option.equals("11")){
           this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));           
        }
        else if (option.trim().equals("1")) {   
            try{
                createItem();                            
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(canvasMenu,"ERROR: Selection was not processed.","", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);                
            }
                                 
            
        }    
        else if (option.trim().equals("2")){
            try{
                updateQtyOfItem();           
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(canvasMenu,"ERROR: Selection was not processed.","", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);                
            }
        }    
        else if (option.trim().equals("3")){
            try{
                addItemToMachine();                               
             }
            catch (Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(canvasMenu,"ERROR: Selection was not processed.","", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);                
            }
        }  
        else if (option.trim().equals("4")){
            try{
                removeItemOnMachine();                           
             }
            catch (Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(canvasMenu,"ERROR: Selection was not processed.","", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);                
            }
        }  
       
        // restock
        else if (option.trim().equals("5")){
            try{
                reStockMachine();                 
             }
            catch (Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(canvasMenu,"ERROR: Selection was not processed.","", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);                
            }
        }  
        //deposit coin
        else if (option.trim().equals("6")){
            try{
                depositCoinOnMachine();                            
             }
            catch (Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(canvasMenu,"ERROR: Selection was not processed.","", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);                
            }
        }  
        // purchase item      
        else if (option.trim().equals("7")){
            try{
                purchaseItemOnMachine();      
             }
            catch (Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(canvasMenu,"ERROR: Selection was not processed.","", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);                
            }
                  
        }  
        else if (option.trim().equals("8")){
            resetItemsOnHand();                 
        } 
        else if (option.equals("9")){
            resetVendingMachineCorea();                  
        }  
        else if (option.trim().equals("10")){
            clearMoneyFromMachine();                 
        }          
        else{
            optionTextF.setText("OPTION NOT RECOGNIZED");       
            optionTextF.selectAll();
        }       
    }
    public void clearMoneyFromMachine(){
        int itemNum, money;
        money = myVendingMachine.clearMoney();        
        updateScreen();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(canvasVending, "Money Cleared. Removed " + money + " cents");                    
        
    }
    
    public void purchaseItemOnMachine(){
        int itemNum, change;
        
        String itemNumS;
        
        itemNumS = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(canvasVending,"Which item would you like purchase on the machine?", null);
        itemNum = Integer.parseInt(itemNumS);
                
        change = myVendingMachine.selectItem(itemNum);
        updateScreen();
        if(change >=0){ 
              
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(canvasVending, "Successfully Purchased\n" + "Your Change is " + change + " cents");                    
          
        }
        else if (change ==-9999){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(canvasVending,"ERROR: Item was not purchased ","", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);                
        }
    }
    public void depositCoinOnMachine(){
        int value;
        boolean success;
       
        String valueS;
        
        valueS = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(canvasVending,"What the value in cents of the coin being deposited?", null);
        value = Integer.parseInt(valueS);
                
        success = myVendingMachine.depositCoin(value);
        updateScreen();
        if(success){             
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(canvasVending, "Coin Accepted");                    
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(canvasVending,"ERROR: Coin Rejected","", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);      
        }   
    }
   
    public void reStockMachine(){
        int itemNum, qty;
        boolean success;
        
        String itemNumS, qtyS;        
        
        itemNumS = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(canvasVending,"Which item would you like restock on the machine?", null);
        itemNum = Integer.parseInt(itemNumS);
        
        qtyS = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(canvasVending,"How what is the quantity that you are adding?", null);
        qty=Integer.parseInt(qtyS);
             
        success = myVendingMachine.reStock(itemNum, qty);
        updateScreen();
        if(success){ 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(canvasVending, "Item Successfully Restocked");          
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(canvasVending,"ERROR: Item was not stocked since it was not found","", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);    
        }    
    }
   
    public void resetItemsOnHand(){
        myOnHandList.clear();   
        updateScreen();
    }
    
    public void resetVendingMachineCorea(){
        myVendingMachine = new VendingMachine();
        updateScreen();
    } 
 
    public void removeItemOnMachine(){
        int itemNum;
        String itemNumS;
        boolean success;
        
        itemNumS = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(canvasVending,"Which item would you like remove on the machine?", null);
        itemNum = Integer.parseInt(itemNumS);
                
        success = myVendingMachine.removeItemType(itemNum);
        updateScreen();
        if(success){             
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(canvasVending, "ITEM REMOVED FROM MACHINE");             
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(canvasVending, "ITEM WAS NOT REMOVED TO MACHINE");             
        }    
    }
   
     public boolean updateQtyOfItem(){
        int itemNum, qty, extra;
        String itemNumS, qtyS;        
        
        itemNumS = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(canvasOnHand,"Which item would you like to update?", null);
        itemNum = Integer.parseInt(itemNumS);
             
        if (itemNum < 0 || itemNum > myOnHandList.size()-1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(canvasOnHand, "ERROR: Could not add qty to item. Index is out of range", "", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);  
            return false;
        }
        qtyS = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(canvasOnHand,"How many are you adding?", null);
        qty=Integer.parseInt(qtyS);
               
        extra = myOnHandList.get(itemNum).addQuantity(qty);
        updateScreen();
        if (extra == -9999){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(canvasOnHand, "ERROR: Could not add qty to item", "", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);  
            return false;
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(canvasOnHand, "Quantity updated. Number of Item Qty  rejected: " + extra);
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    public void addItemToMachine(){
        int itemNum;
        boolean success;
      
        String itemNumS;
        itemNumS = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(canvasOnHand,"Which item would you like add to the machine?", null);
                
        itemNum = Integer.parseInt(itemNumS);
        if (itemNum < 0 || itemNum > myOnHandList.size()-1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(canvasOnHand, "ERROR: Could not add item to vending machine, index out of bounds", "", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);  
        }  
        else{
            success = myVendingMachine.addItemType(myOnHandList.get(itemNum));
            if(success){               
                 myOnHandList.remove(itemNum);    
                 updateScreen();                
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(canvasOnHand, "ITEM ADDED TO MACHINE");                 
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(canvasOnHand, "ITEM WAS NOT ADDED TO MACHINE");              
            }   
        }
    }  
    
    public void updateScreen(){
        updateMachineConsole();
        printItemOnHandList();
    }
    
    
    public void updateMachineConsole(){
        vendingText.setText("VENDING MACHINE\n\n");
        vendingText.append("Current Bank Amount: " + myVendingMachine.getBankAmount());
        vendingText.append("\nCurrent Change Amount: " + myVendingMachine.getChangeAmount());
        vendingText.append("\nCurrent deposited: " + myVendingMachine.getDepositAmount());
        vendingText.append("\n"+myVendingMachine.toString());
        
    }  
    
   
    
    public void printItemOnHandList(){
        onHandText.setText("QUANTITY ON HAND\n\n" + StringFormatter("IndexID", 10) + 
                           StringFormatter("Name", 15) +  StringFormatter("Price", 10) + 
                           StringFormatter("Quantity",10));
        onHandText.append("\n***********************************************");  
        
        if (myOnHandList.isEmpty()){
            onHandText.append("\nThere are no items types");
        }
        else{
            for(int i=0; i<myOnHandList.size(); i++){
                onHandText.append("\n"+NumberFormatter(i, 2) + StringFormatter("", 8)+
                                  StringFormatter(myOnHandList.get(i).getName(),13) + 
                                  NumberFormatter(myOnHandList.get(i).getPrice(), 7) + 
                                  StringFormatter("", 6)+
                                  NumberFormatter(myOnHandList.get(i).getQuantity(), 5));  
            }
            onHandText.append("\n");
        }
    }    
       
    public void createItem(){
        String name, priceS, qtyS;
        int price;
        int qty, extra;
        
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(canvasMenu,"What is the name of this item?", null);
        priceS = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(canvasMenu,"What is the PRICE of this new item?", null);
        qtyS = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(canvasMenu,"What is the QUANTITY you adding?", null);
        
        price = Integer.parseInt(priceS);
        qty = Integer.parseInt(qtyS);
               
        ItemType item = new ItemType(name, price);
        extra = item.addQuantity(qty);
        myOnHandList.add(item);   
        updateScreen();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(canvasMenu, "Item Created. Number of Item Qty  rejected: " + extra);             
    }  
     /***********************************************************************
     * Do not modify the code below. They are functions to assist you with 
     * this assignment
     ***********************************************************************/
    
    /* this method takes in an integer value and field width. It return
     * a string of length fWidth with the integer value right justified    
     */
    public static String NumberFormatter(int value, int fWidth) {
        DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("########");
        String output = myFormatter.format(value); 
        String filler = "";
        if (fWidth - output.length() < 0 ){
            return output.substring(0, fWidth);
        }
        else{
            for(int i=0; i < fWidth - output.length(); i++)
            {
                filler = filler + " ";
            }   
            return filler+output;
        }
    }
    /* this method takes in an double value and field width. It return
     * a string of length fWidth with the double value right justified 
     * with two digits to the right of the the decimal point
     */
    static public String NumberFormatter(double value, int fWidth) {
        DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("########.00");
        String output = myFormatter.format(value); 
        String filler = "";
        if (fWidth - output.length() < 0 ){
            return output.substring(0, fWidth);
        }
        else{
            for(int i=0; i < fWidth - output.length(); i++)
            {
                filler = filler + " ";
            }   
            return filler+output;
        }
    }
    /* this method takes in an string value and field width. It return
     * a string of length fwidth with the string value left justified 
     */
    static public String StringFormatter(String value, int fWidth) {
        String output = value.trim();
        String filler = "";
        if (fWidth - output.length() < 0 ){
            return output.substring(0, fWidth);
        }
        else{
            for(int i=0; i < fWidth - output.length(); i++)
            {
                filler = filler + " ";
            }   
            return output+filler;
        }
    }    
    
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
        if (ev.getSource() == optionTextF)
        {
            option = optionTextF.getText();
            optionTextF.setText("");
            processOptionSelected();
            updateScreen();
        }
    }
    
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {}
    
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {}
    
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {}
    
    
    
    /** The entry main() method */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        VendingDriver2 kf = new VendingDriver2(); // set up the game    
        kf.displayMenu();              
    }      
}
```

Comment: To remove an item type simply remove it from the list `myOnHandList.remove(yourItemType);` and make sure that your jFrame reflects the changes (with a listener, or manually in your method). To restock items just loop through the list `myOnHandList` and set the quantity to whatever you want?